# How to test java methods that works with excel with JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have methods in Java to work with Excel that I am trying to unit test.
I tried a few things here and there but I doesn't work.

I have the following methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createExcel(@RequestBody List<ExcelDto> excelDtos) {
    log.log(Level.INFO, "generate excel started");
    try (InputStream is = GenerateExcelController.class.getResourceAsStream(PATH_TO_TEMPLATE)) {
        this.temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".xlsx");
        try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(temp)) {
            processExcel(excelDtos, is, fs);
            return generateResponse();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot generate excel!", e);
    }
    return null;
}

private void processExcel(List<ExcelDto> productDto, InputStream is, FileOutputStream fs) throws IOException{
    Context context = new Context();
    context.putVar("products", productDto);
    context.putVar("today", LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
    JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, fs, context);
}

private ResponseEntity<byte[]> generateResponse() {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(temp.getPath())) {
        Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(fileInputStream);
        byte[] content = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Download sample .xlsx request completed");
        Files.delete(temp.toPath());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot find temp excel file!", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can someone help me or tell me how to start?

Answer (score 0):

`@Controller` beans are singletons so you must avoid using mutable instance variables e.g. storing temporary file path in `this.temp`. `this.temp` is not request scoped, you current approach won't work when there are multiple concurrent POST requests.

Excel creation logic should probably be extracted to a new `@Service` bean which can be unit tested with a predefined test resources.

```
@Service
public class ExcelService {

  public OutputStream createExcel(InputStream template, List<ExcelDto> products) {
    // read InputStream
    // process template with JxlsHelper
    // return generated Excel as OutputStream
  }

}
```

Comment: Or better to change methods signature to return `File` or filename. In that case it is possible to create a unit-test with some test data, generate Excel file with that test data and then parse it in your unit-test and check that appropriate data was inserted into appropriate cells in tan Excel file